# How to validate a user is putting in two specific letters in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make it so the user can only say A, L, a, or l.

```
//Ask user how they want their winnings
            Console.WriteLine("Congrats on winning {0}! How would you like your winnings?\r\nPlease enter 'L' for a lump sum (15% will be taken) or 'A' for 20 annual payments.", winningsString);
        //capture user's response
       string winTake =  Console.ReadLine();
        //Declare a variable to gold the converted value
        char winChoice;

        //valiadate the user is typing A or L
        while (!char.TryParse("A,L", out winChoice))
        {
            //alert the user the error
            Console.WriteLine("Please only type in A or L and do not leave blank");
            //Re-capture the user's response in the SAME variable as before
            winTake = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char.TryParse` only returns true if the string has a single character. You could use that and an additional check to test if you have a valid input, or do something like this:

```
string winTake = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
while(winTake != "a" && winTake != "l") {
    Console.WriteLine("Please only type in A or L and do not leave blank");
    winTake = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}

switch(winTake) {
    case "a": //do stuff
        break;
    case "l": //do different stuff
        break;
    default: //do a third thing
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use `Console.ReadKey()` instead for `Console.ReadLine()` for getting user input as `char` also suggest a different approach for validating the user input as like the following:

```
char winTake = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar; // gets the input character
char[] validChars = new char[] { 'A', 'a', 'L', 'l' };         
while (!validChars.Any(x => x == winTake))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please only type in A or L and do not leave blank, Retry:"); 
    winTake = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
}
Console.WriteLine("Completed");
```

You can depend of [`Char.ToLower()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.tolower?view=netframework-4.7.2) method for minimizing the items in the `validChars` array. so that the array will contains only lowercase letters and you have to store the input like `char winTake = Char.ToLower(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);`